# USB 3.0 Ethernet Gigabit Adapter Showing Slow Network Speeds

Tags: networking, usb, windows-8.1, drivers

I have an NIC card that was working perfectly fine using Windows 7 and I was getting 50-60Mbps on speedtest.net. I upgraded to 8.1 and for some reason I keep getting an error:

```
This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)

If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the other devices on this system.
```

So I don't think my NIC card has Win8.1 drivers. I disabled it and bought this:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00S5L9K1G/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00S5L9K1G)

But when I installed the latest drivers for 8.1 and plug it in my USB 3.0 port it gives me around 5-6Mbps speeds...and worse it drops packets frequently because if I download a zip file or installer file I get corrupt files or CRC errors...

I've been bumping my head how to fix this with no avail..

Comment: The information for the [code 12 is on the MS site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732199%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Perhaps it is an old card?

Answer (score 0):

It is faulty and should be returned for a replacement.

Comment: Sounds kind of like an opinion.  Aren't we supposed to avoid those?  :-)  Maybe better suited as a comment?

Comment: I was being typically British. Now it is an answer.